# Problems when using XCode 4.2 with any PhoneGap version

Tags: xcode4.2

I'm trying to use several versions of PhoneGap to run XCode 4.2 in Snow Leopard (10.6.8), but the most part of versions that i tried doesn't work, and it generates many kinds of errors.
  Is there some specific version of PhoneGap that i can use?

Thanks!
Douglas!

Answer (score 0):

it should be the version 2.1. Follow this:
http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/10/installing-cordovaphonegap-2-1-for-ios/